# How to use DbContext in separate class library .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to access my dbcontext from my .net core 3.1 MVC project in a class library.  Currently I inject my database into the service collection in `startup.cs`

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        // Handles duplicate entry for email in user table
        builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(u => u.Email)
            .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

However, I'm unsure of how to access this AppDbContext in my class library.  I tried accessing it like i would a controller, but obviously it doesn't know about the DI container.

**More information:
*This library is used for common requests that are made.  It must always be separate from the main web application and the user should never have to code in this class library.  Therefore, I need to be able to access the dbcontext thats in the main web project from the class library.***

Comment: Where is AppDbContext class created?

Comment: in the main application.

Comment: Well you can always do `var context = new AppDbContext()`

Comment: Do you know how to do it for a class that is not a DbContext? Is there something specific with DbContext that prevents your class library to access it or is this a general dependency problem?

Comment: What I normally do is to move the data context to its own library and reuse from there.

Comment: What do you mean access it like you would a controller?

Comment: by using dependency injection.  I'm not even sure if its possible in a class library.  The context name will never change and i know i can't just access a class from a web app in a library if they aren't somehow connected.

Comment: I really feel that you should study more on what DI is and how it can be used. Doing this should be trivial given the right project references.

Comment: They aren't in the same project.  If I had them in the same project or sln i'd be passed this.

Comment: @TheDizzle Whats wrong if you define your `DbConext` in a separate class library then  your existing class library and main web app will reference `DbConext` class library.

Comment: Or Are you developing the class library to use any `DbConext`?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the user never has to change anything in my class library.  If they add tables to their DB, I don't want them to have to update the library

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes developing to use any dbContext

Comment: @TheDizzle Check my answer please. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said you are developing the class library to use any `DbContext` passing by the client of the library then you have to do as follows:

First considering your class library has following interfaces and classes where your `DbContext` will be used:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork 
{
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}

internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private Hashtable _repositories;
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
            _repositories = new Hashtable();

        var type = typeof(T).Name;

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);

            var repositoryInstance =
                Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T)), _dbContext);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (IRepository<T>)_repositories[type];
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
     Task InsertEntityAsync(TEntity entity);
}

internal class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task InsertEntityAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
    }
 }
```

Now write a a service collection extension method in your class library as follows:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
   
    public static void RegisterYourLibrary(this IServiceCollection services, DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        }

        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(uow => new UnitOfWork(dbContext));
    }
}
```

Now in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` of your client application as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName");
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    AppDbContext appDbContext = serviceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();

    services.RegisterYourLibrary(appDbContext); // <-- Here passing the DbConext instance to the class library

    .......
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
 
    public EmployeeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert()
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        await _unitOfWork.Repository<Employee>().InsertEntityAsync(employee);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I passed the dbContext, but it doesn't know any of the models that are set.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to add to this working solution:
--------------------
interface IRepository<TEntity>
        + Task<List<TEntity>> ToListAsync();
        + Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefault();
        + void Empty(TEntity entity);
---------------
class Repository<TEntity>
        + public async Task<List<TEntity>> ToListAsync() => await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        + public async Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefault() => await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        + public void Empty(TEntity entity) => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);

Comment: I tried to achieve using MYSQL, is not working.  Unable to set the dbset

Answer (score 5):

I solved it like this after getting the error from PMC command `Add-Migration InitialCreate`:

```
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Added `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` as `@JoseGonzalez` but I did not want to hard code my connection string in the implementation of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` but instead pick it up from my applications `appsettings.json`.

Final solution looked like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

            var connectionString = configuration
                        .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

I could then use this in my other project like this:

```
var applicationDbContextFactory = new ApplicationDbContextFactory();

using (var dbContext = applicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(args))
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you created your dbcontext in another project/lib you first need to migrated it, And update it. EF uses IDesignTimeDbContextFactory notify entity framwork about the lib.

```
 public class ContextFactoryNeededForMigrations : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext >
    {
        private const string ConnectionString =
            "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EfCoreInActionDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        public EfCoreContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EfCoreContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataLayer"));

            return new EfCoreContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
```

Then you can add it to your startup.cs DI container like this.

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext >( 
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connection,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataLayer")));
```

Here is good tutorial on the subject. [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@speedforcerun/implementing-idesigntimedbcontextfactory-in-asp-net-core-2-0-2-1-3718bba6db84)